# SonarQube: sonar.exclusions parameter cannot exclude a folder

Tags: symfony, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I work on symfony project and I want to exclude some generated code from **sonar analytics**.

I want to exclude a folder named by this path: **src/Application/Sonata**.

I tried many possibilities with sonar exclusions but in vain:

```
sonar.exclusions=src/Application/Sonata/*
sonar.exclusions=src/Application/Sonata/**
sonar.exclusions=src/Application/Sonata/**/*
```

this is my sonar-project.properties file

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=project
sonar.projectName=project
sonar.projectVersion=0.1.3
# Description
sonar.projectDescription=project a base symphony 2
# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=src/Application/Sonata/**/* ,src/project/Resources/public/js/lib/**/*, src/project/Resources/public/js/jquery.validate.js
```

Comment: I need to know what steps did you do. Did you do something like:
1. run a first analyse of the project 2. configure `sonar.exclusions` parameter 3. run a second analyse of the project?

Comment: Those are exactly the steps i do.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After many tests, i found the correct syntax of **sonar.exclusions** clause:

```
sonar.exclusions=src/Application/Sonata/**/*,src/Simuleo5BOBundle/Resources/public/js/lib/**/*,src/Simuleo5BOBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.validate.js
```

Answer (score -9):

Correctly setting exclusions from properties is difficult to get right, which is why it's not [documented](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus). Instead, you should use the UI to set your exclusions.

Comment: This is an excuse for bad practices. Lack of documentation is why it is difficult to get it right.

Comment: In my case, I need to set the exclusions from properties based on different CI stages. I guess more people also need to set exclusions based on some automated jobs. Even though it's difficult to get right, it's our only option. I completely agree with Manzontin on his comment. Also, making something difficult to use is not an excuse to avoid documenting it.

Comment: The UI can't be used in an automated build environment. If it exists for the command line, it should be properly documented, so it can be used correctly.